# how to reserve quantity partially for delivery order in odoo

Tags: odoo-10, odoo, odoo-9

I have one Product with on-Hand Quantity is 600.

and There are Two Delivery Orders, one is for 400 and other is for 500
but i want reserve both order partially by 300 each DO.

how can i do that in odoo9/10/11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood properly the question, you just have to edit the "TODO" column before validating the delivery orders and set up 300 units each.

By doing that you can do partial delivers of 300 units for each delivery order.

Then you have the option to select to "create backorder or not create backorder" depending on if you plan to deliver the remaining quantities later or not.

Note that "ToDo" column is only present if in the sale order you allow "partial delivery of goods" (can't remember the exact term in English).

Hope this helps, not 100% sure if this is what you are asking.